# Using jQuery and Aria Selector to disable a pop-up link

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, wai-aria

I'm using a Wordpress Plugin called [Order Delivery Date for WooCommerce Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/order-delivery-date-for-woocommerce/) that adds a pop-up calendar to the website allowing the user to select a specific date of service which are added as href:

```html
<a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#" aria-current="true" data-date="23" role="button" aria-label="23 March 2023 Thursday">23</a>
```

The plugin does not allow me to remove specific dates from being accessible so I decided to try and do it myself with CSS and jQuery.

I found that I can target the date in question using the CSS below but this still allows the date to be selected by the user:

```
a[data-date="23"] {
display:none!important;
pointer-events:none!important;
background: #e6e6e6!important;
}
```

I continued to research the Stack Overflow forums and came to the conclusion that jQuery would be a better option, so I added the following code to test for a potential solution:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("a").click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Sure enough, all of the links on the website are disabled, but the calendar links remain accessable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you add `tabIndex=-1` to that component, users won't be able to tab to it. This probably won't stop screen reader users using a virtual cursor. You could use `aria-hidden=true` to hide the tags from screen reader users.

That said, I feel like the most accessible answer is one where everyone has the same experience. If it's reasonable for you to just style the missing dates as `display: none`, so that they don't appear at all for anyone, that'll probably be your simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, `display:none`  still does not prevent the user from being able to select the date in question